# Using an adapter with asynchronous task

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a class that extends `BaseAdapter`, which I use for a `ListView`. In the `getView()` method of that class I'm using an `AsyncTask` with a callback method to download an image (once downloaded, I store it, so I don't have to download it again). When the `ListView` loads the items first, only the first item displays an image an then starts to change the images (repeatedly displaying the images of the other items). Later also the other items start showing the same behaviour. After a while they stop cycling the images and each item shows the correct images. If I scroll the `ListView` the items are starting again to cycle the images.

This only happens, if I recycle the `convertView` parameter, that is passed to `getView()`. If I don't the images take very long to show up, and I'm afraid I'm creating too much new Views.

Thanks in advance for any advices, to get this working properly.

Comment: Related, almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview . Has a few libraries that do what @CommonsWare suggests

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to get this going is to dump all your own image loading code and use something that already handles this, like [Square's Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). There are plenty of alternatives if you do not like Picasso.

Otherwise, your tasks will need to be aware of the recycling, so they do not attempt to update an `ImageView` that now needs a different image. For example, you could use `setTag()` and `getTag()` on the `ImageView` to store (and retrieve) the URL the `ImageView` currently needs, and if the image downloaded by the task is some other URL, don't apply it.

But, again, *please* use an existing library for this. It's 2013: few people should be rolling their own download-the-images-for-use-in-`ListView`-rows code anymore.